# Como eu faço para colocar uma lista em descrecente com RecyclerView no Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Eu preciso colocar a lista em descrecente, ou seja que a lista comece a partir da imagem java que deveria ser a primeir imagem. Isso é um RecyclerView

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira ideal seria fazer um `order` no servidor, onde tu pegar os dados da lista.

Mas tu também pode usar um `Collections.reverse(mList);` para reverter a ordem do seu `ArrayList`.